# Work done on the system is negative?

Tags: thermodynamics, work, conventions

I do not understand sentences like "Work done on the system is negative". Total work done on a system is a quantity defined as the line integral of the dot product of the net force vector and the displacement vector, over the path of the system. The sign of the value of work done will depend on the force and displacement vectors. Then how does the original sentence make any sense? And I have heard that this sign is opposite in chemistry to what it is in physics. Can someone clear up this mess?

Comment: *The sign of the value of work done will depend on the force and displacement vectors.* Right, so why are you confused that work can be negative?

Comment: I am not confused about work done, what I am confused about is why do people then say "work done on the system is negative in physics, and positive in chemistry" The question I am asking is not only referring to the opposite signs in physics and chemistry, but also the meaning of assigning such a sign.

Comment: Ask the chemists. You’ve correctly stated how physicists define work. How do chemists define work?

Comment: Alright, I will ask them too.

Comment: Your statement about chemistry was an afterthought introduced by “And…”. It was not the core of your question as written.

Comment: Yes you are right, it wasn't.

Comment: Nor did your question ask about the *meaning* of the sign. Work is a signed quantity because it is more useful when defined this way. Work can either increase or decrease the kinetic energy, depending on whether force is in the same direction as displacement or opposite.

Comment: Ok wait, I think there is a misunderstanding. I am clear about work, and the meaning of the sign of work. What I am asking is, if sign of work is dependent on force and displacement, then what do people mean by the assertion "Work done on the system is negative".

Comment: The work done on a system can be positive or negative, depending on what is happening. Did you read something that made you think work done on every system is always negative? If so, you misunderstood or you read something that was wrong or badly written.

Comment: This is what happens when a sentence is quoted out of context. Where did you read ”Work done on the system is negative”, and what was the system being considered?

Comment: This helps, I did not pay attention to the context and what the system was. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just boils down to the two ways the 1st law of thermodynamics is written:

$$\Delta U=Q-W \  ; \ \Delta U=Q+W$$

The difference simply lies in how you define $W$. In the first equation, $W$ is the work done by the system on its surroundings. Therefore, $W$ is positive when the system expands and negative when it contracts. In the second equation, $W$ is the work done on the system by the surroundings. It's positive if the system contracts (because the surroundings "push" on the sytem) and negative if the system expands.